# SVN Post-commit hook: error 255 when parameterizing email address using SET command

Tags: svn, visualsvn, svn-hooks, post-commit-hook

We use the SVN `Post-Commit` hook to send email notifications when SVN revisions have been submitted to the repository.  I am attempting to create email distribution lists so SVN users can pick which emails are sent to them based on the URL for the file that was committed to the repo.

When I commit changes to the repo and the hook script fires, I get the following error:

> *Completed: At revision: 8494   Error: post-commit hook failed (exit code 255) with output:   Error: @domain.com was unexpected at this
>   time.*

I have unsuccessfully attempted to use escape characters '**^**','**\**' to escape the '*@*', '*.*' and '*;*' characters in the two variables described below.

Can anyone suggest how, if at all, I can properly format the values of the two variables below to pass them to the `VisualSVNServerHook` call?  Thank you!

---

```
set "distroDBA=joe@domain.com;"
set "distroAll=joe@domain.com; sally@domain.com;"

//IF DBA Revision
"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\VisualSVNServerHooks.exe" ^
commit-notification "%1" -r %2 ^
--from $(author)@domain.com --to "%distroDBA%" ^
--smtp-server smtp.domain.com

//ALL Other Revision
"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\VisualSVNServerHooks.exe" ^
commit-notification "%1" -r %2 ^
--from $(author)@domain.com --to "%distroAll%" ^
--smtp-server smtp.domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ran this hook script. However, I've just noticed a couple of problems:

`set "distroAll=joe@domain.com; sally@domain.com;"`

Remove whitespace after semicolon and remote the last whitespace, too. And it seems that quote signs are unnecessary for your SET statements.